# ImageMagick and Paperclip problem

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, imagemagick

I've got a problem with ImageMagick and Paperclip.

I'm using on localhost rails3, ruby1.9.2, imagemagick 6.5.8 and paperclip as gem in version 2.3.8.

On production (server) I have rails3, roby1.9.2, imagemagick 6.6.7-4 and the same paperclip as above.

When uploading photos on localhost everything is fine.

But on server my problem appear. It gets error:

> [paperclip] identify -format %wx%h
>   '/tmp/stream20110204-15633-3wdd5s.jpg[0]'
>   2>/dev/null
>
> [paperclip] An error was received
>   while processing:
>
> Paperclip::NotIdentifiedByImageMagickError:
>   /tmp/stream20110204-15633-3wdd5s.jpg
>   is not recognized by the 'identify'
>   command.

(the last paragraph is in brackets but I don't know how to avoid hiding it).

Anyone know what's going on?

edit:

All the time I search for some solve and seems that it is problem with ImageMagick. I uploaded some .jpg file on server and try run command "identify file.jpg" and... there is an error:

> identify: no decode delegate for this image format `file.jpg' @ error/constitute.c/ReadImage/532.

hmm...

Answer (score 1):

Possibly Paperclip doesn't know where to find the ImageMagick binaries. Have you tried setting up an initializer for Paperclip in `config/initializers/paperclip.rb` ?

Set:

```
Paperclip.options[:image_magick_path] = "/usr/bin"
```

On your system you might need /usr/local/bin, or something else entirely. You can find out where the 'identify' binary and other ImageMagick binaries are located by typing:

```
which identify
```

If the answer is `/usr/bin/identify`, then you know to set image_magick_path to /usr/bin

Comment: I found an error which causes error above. The JPG library didn't existed in imagemagick... but now I have problems with Paperclip. Now is says: 

[paperclip] /usr/local/bin/identify -format %wx%h '/tmp/stream20110204-9523-3nv56k.jpg[0]' 2>/dev/null
[paperclip] /usr/local/bin/convert '/tmp/stream20110204-9523-3nv56k.jpg[0]' -resize "130x170>" '/tmp/stream20110204-9523-3nv56k20110204-9523-13uckju' 2>/dev/null
[paperclip] An error was received while processing: #<Paperclip::PaperclipError: There was an error processing the thumbnail for stream20110204-9523-3nv56k>

your tip didn't helped...

Answer (score 0):

If adding Paperclip.options[:command_path] = "/usr/local/bin/" doesn't work try installing  ImageMagick with common delegates:

> mkdir /sources    cd /sources
>
> wget
>   ftp://ftp.imagemagick.org/pub/ImageMagick/ImageMagick.tar.gz
>
> tar xvfz ImageMagick.tar.gz
>
> cd ImageMagick-6.6.7-8

Here comes the part makes difference

> ./configure --disable-static
>   --with-modules --without-perl --without-magick-plus-plus --with-quantum-depth=8
>
> make
>
> sudo make install